# Contour Integral of irrational polynomial from -1 to 1

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I've been stuck at htis contour integral problem for a few hours now, and seem to be hitting brick walls.

$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x^4}dx\,,
$$

I tried a trig substitution $x=\cos{\theta}$ but noticed all the poles were the unit circle and I didn't know how to proceed.

$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{1+\cos^4{\theta}}d\theta\,,
$$

Next I thought maybe a rectangular contour but the contours that go vertically from $1$ to $1+i\infty$ and $-1+i\infty$ to $-1$ didn't seem to cancel, or I wasn't able to show that it does. I manipulated it for awhile.

$$
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{1-(1+iy)^2}}{1+(1+iy)^4}dy + \int_{0}^{-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-(1+iy)^2}}{1+(1+iy)^4}dy
$$

I naively wrote the trig integral in terms of z, but the denominator is an 8th order polynomial.

$$
i\oint \frac{2z^5-4z^3+2z}{z^8+4z^6+22z^4+4z^2+1} dz
$$

I think this might be getting closer to a solution, but how can I find the poles by hand?

Comment: Did you try the "dumb-bell" contour? (small circle around +1, then over to -1, small circle around it, back to +1). Since your integrand is holomorphic outside this, you can move the dumb-bell contour out to infinity, seeing that it is 0. At the same time, the values of it on $(-1,+1)$ differ... Similar trick to keyhole/Hankel contour?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by **@paul garrett**, dog-bone contour (dumbbell contour) works perfectly. Indeed, consider the contour $\mathcal{C}$ given as follows:

$\hspace{12em}$[image: contour]

With the principal branch cut, as the radius/band-width of $\mathcal{C}$ goes to zero,

\begin{align*}
\oint_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{i\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}}{i(z^4+1)} \, dz
&\longrightarrow
\int_{-1-0^+i}^{1-0^+i} \frac{i\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}}{z^4+1} \, dz
- \int_{-1+0^+i}^{1+0^+i} \frac{i\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}}{z^4+1} \, dz \\
&\quad = 2\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^4+1} \, dx.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, Residue Theorem tells that

\begin{align*}
\oint_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{i\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}}{z^4+1} \, dz
&= - 2\pi i \sum_{a \ : \ a^4 + 1 = 0} \underset{z=a}{\mathrm{Res}} \, \frac{i\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}}{z^4+1} \\
&= \pi \sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}.
\end{align*}

(In order to use Residue Theorem, consider a large circle, apply Residue Theorem to the region enclosed by this circle and $\mathcal{C}$, and then let the radius of the circle go to $\infty$.) Therefore

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^4+1} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{2(\sqrt{2}-1)}. $$

Comment: Thank you! I have one question though, why don't your integrals annihilate each other? I noticed you introduced an $\frac{i}{i}$ in the first integral?

Comment: @walczyk, That's the beauty of branch cut. Test main observation is that $\sqrt{-x\pm0^+i}=\pm i\sqrt{x}$ for $x\geq0$ when using the principal branch cut.

Comment: @SanchulLee Ahh I remember now, it picks up a $e^{i\pi}$ around the cut no?

Comment: Tes. That's true :)

Comment: I was just thinking... this contour, doesn't it not encircle any poles??  Or, rather, you are saying it's possible to deform it into a giant circle? So it encloses every pole?

Comment: @walczyk, It is more like the latter one. When inflating the contour $\mathcal{C}$ to a large circle, you have to engulf poles of the integrand. The cost of this inflating process can be computed by Residue Theorem applied to the intermediate region. Finally, one can check that the integral over the large circle vanishes as the radius goes to infinity.

Comment: one last question, why do your integrals have factors of i that don't appear in the original integral?

Comment: @walczyk, That cancels out the effect of branch cut. To be specific, this takes care of the following computation: $$ \forall x \in [-1, 1] \ : \quad \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \sqrt{(-x \pm i\epsilon) - 1} \sqrt{(-x \pm i\epsilon) + 1} = \pm i \sqrt{1-x^2}, $$ where all $\pm$ are of the same sign simultaneously.

Comment: I have a hard time following why the x now has a minus sign in front of it, and 1 now how has alternating plus and minus.. How do I do that calculation? should I pull an $\sqrt{\pm i}$ from each side? that turns it it to $\sqrt{\pm ix + \epsilon \pm i} \sqrt{\pm ix + \epsilon \mp i}$. Expanding gets $\sqrt{1-x^2 + \epsilon^2 + \pm2ix\epsilon} $

Comment: @walczyk, Ah, I accidentally inserted $-x$ instead of $x$. So it means that, for each $x\in[-1,1]$, we have $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\sqrt{(x+i\epsilon)-1}\sqrt{(x+i\epsilon)+1}=i\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ and $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\sqrt{(x-i\epsilon)-1}\sqrt{(x-i\epsilon)+1}=-i\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$

Comment: ah thank you for the quick reply! I'll work through your suggestion now :) Why are you able to make the 1 alternate instead of the x? because we begin with $sqrt{1-x^2}$

Comment: @walczyk, Glad it helped! Another remark is that, in the above limits, $\sqrt{(x\pm i\epsilon)+1}$ simply converges to $\sqrt{x+1}$ as the inside of the square root does not cross the principal branch cut. On the other hand, the inside of the square root $\sqrt{(x\pm i\epsilon)-1}$ approaches the principal branch cut from above/below (according to the choice of sign $\pm$) and picks up different signs accordingly.

Comment: I think I understand more now. In the beginning you pulled out an $i$ so you can make this argument. Doesn't both terms approach the branch cut, depending if you are at -1 or 1?

Comment: @walczyk, When $x=-1$, the inside of the square root $\sqrt{(x\pm i\epsilon)+1}$ also touches the branch cut as you pointed out, but this causes little harm. Indeed, the whole point is that the principal square root $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0)$ (notice that the origin is included in the region of continuity)!

Comment: I am not good at this :)

Comment: @walczyk, I understand that this computation can be uneasy to anyone who have seen this his/her first time, as I was. Perhaps it will be a bit easier to draw all the relevant information (branch cut for each square root, contour, poles, etc) onto the complex plane and see how the integrand behaves along the contour.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how to show the function gets a minus sign when it goes around a branch point... Is there another way to show this? Maybe using the polar form of complex numbers? The claim is $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \sqrt{1 + x \pm i\epsilon}\sqrt{1 - x \mp i\epsilon} = \pm i \sqrt{1-x^2}$ yes?

Comment: @walczyk, One needs to be very careful when dealing with square root. It seems to me that you tried something like $i\sqrt{x\pm i\epsilon-1}=\sqrt{1-x\mp i\epsilon}$, but this equality fails if we interpret square roots of both sides as principal square root (the square root where the branch cut is chosen as $(-\infty, 0]$). That is why I deliberately wrote $i\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}$ instead of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. As for your second question, polar form can be helpful :)

Comment: I can't seem to get the imaginary parts of the integral out of the residues :( this is so frustrating. Residue of $\sqrt{1-x^2}/(1+x^4)$ for $x=\pm e^{i\pi /4}$ I get $\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{i\pi/2}}}{(e^{i\pi /4} + e^{i\pi /4})(e^{i\pi /4}+e^{i3\pi /4})(e^{i\pi /4}-e^{3i\pi /4})}$ $= 1/(4i) \sqrt{\sqrt{2}e^{i5\pi /4}}$

Comment: wow, that's very subtle, how you wrote that. Hm.... Do you have any books to recommend?

Comment: @walczyk, I studied complex analysis from [Stein & Shakarchi](https://books.google.com/books?id=0ECHh9tjPUAC&dq=stein+shakarchi+complex+analysis&source=gbs_navlinks_s), which is quite an excellent book. But I cannot recall if I learned this particular set of techniques from this very book.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to compute 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{1+\cos^4{\theta}}d\theta\,.$$
Let $t=\tan\theta$. Then 
$$\sin^2\theta=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2},\ \cos^2\theta=\frac{1}{1+t^2},\ d\theta=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}.$$
Plugging them in we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{t^2}{(1+t^2)^2+1}dt.$$
You can find the roots of the denominator easily. So you can use any method you like, say residues or partial fractions, to compute the integral.

Comment: is there a name for this substitution? It's extremely clever.

Comment: I don't know. The substitution $t=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ is more famous which solves all integrals of rational functions of trigonometric functions. But in many cases $t=\tan\theta$, $t=\sin\theta$ or $t=\cos\theta$ will suffice.

Comment: how can we show that the integral remains unchanged when we change the integrand's limits from [0,pi] to [-pi/2,pi/2]? I think there must be a simple way of showing it, but I dunno how exactly

Comment: You can see that the integrand has period $\pi$. So you can integrate over any interval of length $\pi$.